# How to debug webpage on nokia lumia 920

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, nokia

I created a wordpress website but I get the feedback that one of the menu's is not showing on a nokia lumia 920. Is there a way to simulate this ?

Comment: get the broswer details, since NOKIA LUMIA I think it must be IE 10 or 11.  Get it screen resolution and then reduce your screen resolution in your desktop IE browser.  By this way you can simulate/reproduce the bug.

Comment: IE also has an emulation mode for mobile devices in the developer console.

Answer (score 2):

You can use IE Emulation mode in developer tools (F12) and select `Windows phone`